# Does iSeries DB2 have good optimizer?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

MS SQL developer wading into iSeries DB2 here.

I was asked to re-write some report SQL queries taking forever to run and they are enormous, joining dozens of tables etc.

However when I approached it by using typical MS SQL optimization steps, such as replacing NOT EXISTS with joins, I did not initially see any improvement. Should I bother or the optimizer is taking care of the obvious things like that?

Comment: FWIW, on this site we try to [focus on specific programming problems][http://stackoverflow.com/about]. We generally prefer that broader database questions be posted on our [DBA site][http://dba.stackexchange.com/]. Many of the same people are there, but you may hear from someone who has more specialized technical expertise.

Answer (score 2):

DB/2 is completely different than MS SQL and I wouldn't expect many hand optimizations to make the same impact.

There are a number of factors related to DB/2 performance and optimization.  I would suggest starting with the documentation about [optimizing query performance using query optimization tools](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzajq/rzajqkickoff.htm).

Running your query through [Visual Explain](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzajq/visexpl.htm), for example, should provide a clearer answer.

---

[IBM i Access for Windows ODBC performance](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaik/rzaikodbcperfconsd.htm)

Comment: You would if you only saw the queries. They are horrible. Unfortunately, I only have ODBC connection to the server.

Comment: @ajeh You can usually install iSeries Access directly from the server and use the ODBC credentials to connect.  That should give you access to the profiling tools that you need.

Comment: I was given access to a box with visual explain and it is now running explain on the query for 50 straight minutes. The query itself takes about 15. Thus I am back to square 1 with the the question: how bad are the numerous nested selects with unions and exists/not exists for DB2 optimizer? If this was MS SQL I would rewrite this using a stored proc with temp tables. Would DB2 benefit from that approach?

Comment: IBM's DB2 for i performance experts would generally steer you away from temp tables, but suggest common table expressions instead. Proper indexes are a vital factor.  JamesA gave a good link.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most obvious thing to check is to make sure you have good indexes for your joins. If not then create them. Indexes have much less performance impact on DB2 for i.

Comment: I believe this is the case. The problem is that the queries are absolutely un-manageable as they include dozens of joined sub-selects, some of which are unions and many include `where exists` and `where not exists`.

Comment: In my humble experience, `exists` logic tends to perform rather badly compared to join or `in` logic.  YMMV.

Comment: This application actually has no indexes whatsoever - they use keyed logical files instead. I tried replacing all exists/not exists with joins and it made no differece.

Comment: As long as a logical file [LF] is keyed, it contains (or shares) an IBM i index which serves the same purpose as a DB2 index, although not necessarily as efficiently. If you are on an older release, referencing a logical rather than the physical file [PF] may cause the system to use the older CQE optimizer rather than SQE. In which case query the PFs and the optimizer will pick the best available index (or LF). Many LFs have WHERE logic which may disqualify them if not also in a PF-based query. Which OS release  are you using? Is your Navigator at that (or later) release, plus service pack?

Comment: How long does this run on SQL Server?

Comment: You might want to consider posting the query on DBA.stackexchange.com with relevant details.

Comment: Version 05.04.0014. Navigator v7 r1 mod level 0

Comment: If your server is running IBM i 7.1, then you need to upgrade IBM i Access for Windows to 7.1 as well, and install the latest service pack. Navigator v5r4 doesn't support DB2 for i 7.1, which probably accounts for the problem with Visual Explain.

Comment: Within 7.1 new features have been rolled out by means of "Technology Refresh" patches.  To find out what patch level DB2 is at, use `WRKGRPPTF SF99701`.